# Laravel Datatables - Error with undefined function

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-datatables

I am facing an issues bring Datatables into my existing laravel application.
I have follow a couple of videos and getting stuck.

I have the following in my MembersController.php file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Alert;
use DataTables;

use App\Member;

class MembersController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    //

    return view('members.index');
    //, compact('members'));
}

function getdata()
{
    $members = Member::where('active', '!=', 'N')->where('member_type', 
'=', 'League')->get();
    return Datatables::of($members)->make(true);
}
```

I have the following in my Route/web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('/members', 'MembersController')->middleware('auth');
// Ajax requests
Route::get('members/getdata', 'MembersController@getdata')->name('members.getdata');
```

I have the following Script in my members/index.blade

```
<script>
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#table').Datatable({
         "processing": true,
         "serverSide": true,
         "ajax": "{{ rount('members.getdata')}}",
         "columns" :[
             {"data": "first_name"},
             {"data": "last_name"},
             {"data": "memberrank->rank"},
             {"data": "ActiveKids->sum('balance')"}
         ]
     });         

      $("#search").keyup(function(){
      _this = this;

      // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
      $.each($("#roll tbody tr"), function() {

if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === 
-1)
        {  
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else
        {
           $(this).show();
        }
      });
   });
 });
 </script>
```

However I get the following error:
"Call to underined function rount()

This points the issue to the javascript

```
"ajax": "{{ rount('members.getdata')}}",
```

Comment: What is this rount? it should be `route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"ajax": "{{ route('members.getdata')}}",
```

Comment: Thanks, while this solved my error, my table was empty. So back to the drawing board. Interesting that the Youtube view used rount and worked